# data extraction by tagging using java

Tags: java, lucene, uima

I have a requirement where i have collection of text files (unstructured data), based on the user input(tag), i need to search for the tag term in  all the files. if found i need to return the paragraph where the search term occurred.

for example: spec.txt file having the following content

> The ABX earphones with Bluetooth support have been rolled into the
>   Indian market for a price of Rs 5490. They’re available in two color
>   choices of black and red, and come with a rechargeable battery which
>   can be juiced up via the supplied micro-USB cable.
>
> The ABX is said to be capable of rendering up to 10.5 hours of
>   playback once fully charged. It also features an integrated microphone
>   that lets you attend to voice calls. The earphones come with digital
>   noise cancellation technology and a Bluetooth receiver/connector.

in the above 2 paragraphs, if the user enters the tag, "price" it should return "price = Rs 5490" or it should return the paragraph where it identified the term "price"

i have checked UIMA and lucene, but not getting any idea how to do this, can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Lucene Highlighter? It will not return whole paragraph but it will return highlighted content where "price" is found.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply... yeah i found the solution, i m using solr highlighter, by adjusting fragment size of the snippet returned by the solr response we can get the paragraph where the search term exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u for ur reply... yeah i found the solution, i m using solr highlighter, by adjusting fragment size of the snippet returned by the solr response we can get the paragraph where the search term exists